# При попытке подключения .h файла выдает ошибка: stray ‘\320’ in program

Tags: c++

При попытке подключения .h файла выдает ошибка: stray ‘\320’ in program. От чего это может быть? Пробовал скомпилировать без реализации в .сpp файле, по сути подключил .h файл в пустой .cpp файл, но она никуда не исчезла...

Вот так выглядит .h файл, работаю в QtCreator компилятор gcc под unix

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "string.h"
#include <map>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include<vector>
#include "core.h"
#include "httpparser.h"
#include "htttpheader.h"
#include <sys/epoll.h>
class ConeThreadPool{
    public:
         ConeThreadPool(unsigned int numberОfThreads, int maxfd);
         ~ConeThreadPool();
         int getFreeThread(epoll_event events[]);
         void setFd(int thradFD, int fd);
    private:
        int threadManager;
        unsigned int numberОfThreads;
        std::vector<int> threadList;
        int getFD(int socket);
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки. Удалить неиспользуемые хидеры.

Comment: У вас буква  'O' - русская в 'numberОfThreads'. Я посмотрел с помощью `xxd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо копировали код или писали не сами? Перепишите из одного файлика в другой, в смысле перепечатайте, судя по всему попался служебный символ.

Comment: Копировал свой код из одного сзз файла в другой